# When im moving a class to a header file i get an error C++

Tags: c++, class, header-files

Something annoying is going on here and I hope the community can help me :). My program is working correctly when I have my class in the `cpp` file. When I move my class code into a header file the program throws errors. Please instruct me. Thank you!

`.cpp file`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "CSquare.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CSquare alo(1,"name");
}
```

`CSquare.h`

```
#pragma once
class CSquare
{
private:
    int squareCode;
    string squareName;
public:
    CSquare(int, string);
    void setCode(int);
    void setName(string);
};

CSquare::CSquare(int inputSquareCode, string inputSquareName)
{
    setCode(inputSquareCode);
    setName(inputSquareName);
}

void CSquare::setCode(int inputSquareCode)
{
    squareCode = inputSquareCode;
}

void CSquare::setName(string inputSquareName)
{
    squareName = inputSquareName;
}
```

I have also tried moving the `#include string` in both files but still, nothing seems to fix the problem :/

```
error C3646: 'squareName': unknown override specifier error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'string' C2061: syntax 
error: identifier 'string' – Mash 16 mins ago  
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'string' 
error C2065: 'inputSquareName': undeclared identifier 
error C2065: 'string': undeclared identifier error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'inputSquareName' 
error C2143: syntax 
error: missing ';' before '{' 
error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) 
error C2661: 'CSquare::CSquare': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments –
```

Comment: Paste your errors

Comment: If this is Visual Studio copy the text of the error messages from the Output Tab.

Comment: error C3646: 'squareName': unknown override specifier
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'string'
C2061: syntax error: identifier 'string'

Comment: error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'string'
error C2065: 'inputSquareName': undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'string': undeclared identifier
error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'inputSquareName'
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
error C2661: 'CSquare::CSquare': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments

Comment: @Mash write the relevant information into the question. And use code blocks for error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CSquare.h` lacks the definition for the type `string`.

Solution: Perhaps you intended to use `std::string`. In that case you must include `<string>` in `CSquare.h` and use the scope resolution operator to refer to the `string` declared in the `std` namespace. See the first sentence of this paragraph for an example.

---

`CSquare.h` contains definitions to non-inline functions. If the header is included in more than one translation unit, then you violate the [*one definition rule*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

> In the entire program, an object or non-inline function cannot have more than one definition

Solution: Either define the functions in a single source file, or declare the functions `inline`.